# "Sit down and rest a 'while'." Shouldn't while be a noun in this case?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning, articles, usage

Now, I know this is really weird since they should've italicized *a while* and not just *while* in this specific sentence, but since they've only italicized *while*, and since it comes after an article *a*, shouldn't it be considered a noun?

My teacher says that it should be an adverb since *a while* is collectively considered to be an adverb, as it describes about the verb *rest*.

Comment: It might help to consider *Sit down and rest **briefly***, and *Sit down and rest **a bit.***

Comment: Who are the 'they' who have used the italics?

Comment: Have just seen Dhanishtha's comment below.

Comment: "While" is a noun and the "a" marks "a while" as a noun phrase. The noun phrase is functioning as a temporal adjunct (adverbial) in clause structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How we name something is a matter of convention; and in some cases, which words we use to describe something depends on what aspect of the thing strikes us as most significant.

According to the Online Etymological Dictionary, “while” is descended from a word in Old English that meant “time” and clearly was a noun. However, it is used in that sense in Modern English only in some stock phrases, *e.g.* “it’s been a while.” Thus, if we want to stress the basic rules of English grammar, where articles are attached only to nouns, your viewpoint is valid.

If, however, we want to look at things functionally, your viewpoint leads us to an absurdity. I know what it means to rest a horse or a team of athletes who have been exercising. It means to let them cease doing anything demanding. It necessarily pertains to the animate world. If we “rest a while,” does that mean we are letting time take a breather? Of course not. “A while” is not the direct object of “rest” in terms of meaning. What we have is an ellipsis

> Sit down and rest [for] a while.

Functionally, the phrase “for a while” acts as an adverb by qualifying the verb with respect to duration just like

> Sit down and rest briefly.

So, we have a phrase that, interpreted as whole, functions as an adverb even though the pieces of the phrase include an article and an ancient noun. If we think about meaning and realize that time does not and cannot take a break, we think “adverbial phrase” and ignore the individual words. If we think in a typological fashion and realize that only words classified as nouns take articles, we think noun and ignore meaning.

So both you and your teacher are correct; you just are concentrating on different things. Your teacher is thinking of “a while” as a complete phrase and analyzing the phrase’s function. You are thinking of classifying the individual words.

Comment: Snap! I just posted a comment contrasting ***briefly*** with ***a while***, before scrolling down to find it already there in your answer!

Comment: Don’t you just hate when that happens.

Comment: I don't mind so much here, because I still think I brought something to the party with ***a bit***, which no-one else has mentioned yet on this page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right. **While** is a noun in this case. It is defining a length or an expanse of time. I didn't quite understand  about the whole deal of italicising the word though.

**"While"** when used as a noun, is preceded by the article **"a"**, hence it is the only part that should be italicised (this style of writing is only prevalent in Grammar books, people usually do not write in this way while everyday writing).

Examples:

- He only had to wait a short while.
- It was a while before any waiter took their order.
- I only stayed for a short while.
- I haven't seen him for a while.
- They chatted for a while.

[Source of examples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/while) You can refer to the part where it is marked as noun (which is a little later in the section).

---

As pointed out by @JeffMorrow, *while* can be used with the definite and the indefinite article alike.

- **all the while** - for all of a period of time [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all-the-while)

> There I was thinking you were hard at work and you were upstairs in bed all the while!

> She pretended to be asleep, but all the while she was watching him.

- **(every) once in a while** - sometimes, but not often or not regularly [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/every-once-in-a-while)

> Make sure you take a break every once in a while.

> We see each other every once in a while.

Both of the above phrases use them as noun, and not adverb.

Comment: First, I have never seen “a while” italicized as though it were a foreign phrase. Is that a convention in Indian English? Second, it is simply false that the definite article is never used with the noun “while.” For example, “all the while” is a common and perfectly acceptable locution. Please consider some minor edits to your answer.

Comment: @JeffMorrow It is followed in children's Grammar book to distinguish which word or phrase they are talking about. Sometimes children get confused which word is being referred (I used to) when multiple occurrences of the same word is present. It can be written in bold as well. I never said definite article is never used. I have written "usually"..but yeah it may be confusing. I will edit it to include the other uses. Thank you.